# select new in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, generics

```
var CountryCompanyDB = from b in dc.PropertyCompanies where (b.Country.Contains(txtSearch)) select;

Session["CountryCompany"] = CountryCompanyDB.ToList();

if(test==1)
{
    var result = (List<PropertyCompany >)Session["CountryCompany"];
}
```

this worked fine

**but i want**

```
var CountryCompanyDB = from b in dc.PropertyCompanies where (b.Country.Contains(txtSearch)) select new {b.id , b.name};

Session["CountryCompany"] = CountryCompanyDB.ToList();

if(test==1)
{
    var result = (List<PropertyCompany new {b.id , b.name}>)Session["CountryCompany"];//does not can this work
}
```

i want select new of Session["CountryCompany"] how can perform this work.

**Edit**

```
class   kbc {
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public string  name { get; set; }
}


  var CountryCompanyDB = from b in dc.PropertyCompanies where (b.Country.Contains(txtSearch)) select new { id=b.IdCompany ,name=b.NameCompany} ;

 if(test==1)
{
    var result = (List<kbc>)Session["CountryCompany"];
}
```

sayError:
     Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int64,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FullSearch+kbc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous objects work as long as you are in local scope. Now once you have stored it in session and retrieved it back compiler needs to know the type of retrieved object. so you can create some DTO type of thing to accomplish this task like

```
public class DTOCompany
{
  public int id{get;set;}
  public string name{get;set;}
}
```

you can use this object in you linq query like

```
var CountryCompanyDB = from b in dc.PropertyCompanies where (b.Country.Contains(txtSearch)) select new DTOCompany{id=b.id ,name = b.name};
```

when retrieving it back from session you can cast it as list of DTOCompany like

```
var result = (List<DTOCompany>)Session["CountryCompany"];
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int64,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FullSearch+DTOCompany
]

Comment: you probably missed `select new DTOCompany{id=b.id ,name = b.name}` part in Linq query

Answer (score 1):

Define your `PropertyCompany` in your LINQ statement:

```
var CountryCompanyDB = from b in dc.PropertyCompanies
                       where b.Country.Contains(txtSearch)
                       select new PropertyCompany()
                       { 
                          ID = b.id,
                          Name = b.name,
                       };
```

Where `ID` and `Name` are possible property names of your `PropertyCompany` class.

Comment: @testcomeria: You should basically avoid using an anonymous type in your session. Instead, use the same type you are trying to retrieve from it, in this case, the `PropertyCompany` class. Notice, how I changed the `select` clause from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types should only be use as intermediate for more complex algorithm. If you want to save result into variable or pass it into method, you should create specific class.

Answer (score 0):

`new {b.id , b.name}` is an anonymous type, so you can't refer to it conveniently. You should use either a *regular* class that is defined in your code, or maybe a `Tuple<int,string>` (i.e. `select Tuple.Create(b.id, b.name)`) - then:

```
var result = (List<Tuple<int,string>>)Session["CountryCompany"];
```

Comment: @testcomeria explain more about...?

Comment: about Tuple.create(b.id,b.name)

Comment: Please write full example i does not understand

Comment: That *is* a full example.... you change the `select` to `select Tuple.Create(b.id, b.name)` which is implicitly a `Tuple<int,string>` - and store it with `.ToList()` like before. Then; when you get it back out you cast to what you know it to be - a `List<Tuple<int,string>>`

Answer (score 0):

`Session["CountryCompany"]` won't be holding a `List<PropertyCompany>` but instead it would be a generic List of i presume like `<string,string>`. Check out the type when you perform the `ToList()` part.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, with anonymous type.. is use them in select and after use it in foreach.

```
var q = _someCollection.Where(c => c.Id == 100).Select (new { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name});

foreach(var p in q) {
   var id = p.Id;
}
```

This would work, because actually, compiler know the type of new { Age = c.Age, Position = c.Pos} (it generates additional info for that).

As soon as you convereted to List, then you had converted to object (put to Session), you cound not get type information any more.

I would introduce some real type `CountryInfo` and changed query;

```
var q = _someCollection.Where(c => c.Id == 100).Select(new ContryInfo { Id = c.Id, Name = c.Name}).

Session["a"] = q.ToList();

var list = (IList<ContryInfo>)Session["a"];
```

Comment: q.tolist() say error : Explicit construction of entity type 'PropertyCompany' in query is not allowed