# How to join 2 tables with a new compute field

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

i'm new to LINQ and i'm facing a problem, here what i try to get:

```
Table A:
Field: Name A
Field: Id_A

Table B:
Field: Name B
Field: TableA_Id_A As New List(Of String)

Result Expected:
Field: New value true or false: to indicate if Id_A is include in Table B.TableA_Id_A
Field: Name A
Field: Id_A
```

In fact i want to list in grid the table A with a column which contains a checkbox and is checked if the item is include in table B (field TableA_Id_A).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = TableA.Select(a=> New{ exist = TableB.TableA_Id_A.Contains(a.Id_A), NameA = a.NameA, IdA = a.IdA})
```

Check about linq synatx here: [LINQ: .NET Language-Integrated Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)
[select new in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743319/select-new-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found another solution:

```
        Dim _result = (From _tblA In TableA _
                       From _tblB In TableB _
                       Let _NewValue = IIf(_tblB.TableA_Id_A.Contains(_tblA.Id_A), True, False) _
                      Select _tblA, _NewValue).Distinct.ToList
```

Thanks Niranjan Kala, i will try your solution.